# Excel VBA get dynamic values from a source sheet to destination sheet

Tags: excel, vba, import, match, lookup

I am new to VBA and I have been trying this for a while but so far no luck.

I have a workbook with 2 dynamic sheets 1 and 2. Each sheet has Column A(Tag ID),B(ID variation),C(values). I want to copy column C from sheet2 into column D of sheet1 if values of Column A&B in sheet1 match A&B of sheet2. There is also a chance that sheet 2 might not have all the entries for samples and only a portion of sample names will be available.

[image: sheet1]

[image: sheet2]

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Does your version of Excel enable you to execute excel spill ranges? You can test this if you create a formula on either sheet somewhere off outside of your work that is `=A1:A3`. If this creates three cells (spilled so to speak), you do. If you only get the value of `A1`, you don't.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you could create references to sheet 1 and 2, and loop through one of the sheets, while checking existence of each entry in the other sheet, and copying the value over if A&B match.

It's been a while since I've written VBA and this is not a great solution performance-wise, but this might help you get started.

Rough Example (definitely not syntactically correct, and is missing assigning sheet1 and sheet2 to the actual workbooks):

```
Dim sheet1 As Worksheet 
Dim sheet2 As Worksheet

For row In sheet1
    For row2 In sheet2
        If row.Range("A").Value == row2.Range("A").Value
            If row.Range("B").Value == row2.Range("B").Value
                row.Range("D").Value = row2.Range("C").Value
```

Comment: would it be possible for you put an example code for the first solution you mentioned to reference sheets? I have added some images

Comment: do you have to use VBA for this?  Seems a bit overkill for something that can be achieved with standard formulas.

Comment: The reason for using VBA is that these sheets are also being imported from other sources which will have different number of rows(in addition to A,B and C) and each time I would have to put the syntaxes for these cells. Considering the amount of data, VBA seemed easier

Comment: I've added a pseudo-example.  VBA does sound like the right choice

Answer (score 0):

If Column C is just numeric data, then you could accomplish what you're trying to do without VBA and just use [SumIfs](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2014/11/12/excel-sumifs-sumif-multiple-criteria/) or [SumProduct](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-sumproduct-function).

Insert the below formula in your `sheet1` cell `D1` and drag down.

```
=SUMIFS(Sheet2!C:C,Sheet2!A:A,A1,Sheet2!B:B,B1)
```

Also, if you have [Excel spill range feature](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2021/04/07/excel-spill-range/), you could use a dynamic formula that would self-populate as rows are added.

```
=FILTER(SUMIFS(Sheet2!C:C,Sheet2!A:A,A1:A999999,Sheet2!B:B,B1:B999999),NOT(ISBLANK(A1:A999999)))
```

[image: Sample Result]